# Fields in a “Serializable” class should either be transient or serializable squid : S1948

Tags: java, sonarqube, serializable

When I used SonarQube to examine my Java code, some warning popped up: Fields in a “Serializable” class should either be transient or serializable squid : S1948.
[image]

My code:

```
public class ServiceResult implements Serializable {
    public static final Integer INTERNAL_ERROR = 500;
    public static final Integer SERVICE_EXCEPTION = 501;
    public static final Integer PARAM_ERROR = 999;
    public static final int AUTHORITY_ERROR = 401;
    public static final Integer SUCCESS = 200;
    public static final Integer INPUT_ERROR = 402;

    private Integer code = SUCCESS;
    private Object msg;

    public ServiceResult() {

    }

    public ServiceResult(Integer code, Object msg) {
        this.code = code;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Object getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(Object msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public static ServiceResult fail(String msg) {
        ServiceResult serviceResult = new ServiceResult();
        serviceResult.setCode(INTERNAL_ERROR);
        serviceResult.setMsg(msg);
        return serviceResult;
    }

    public static ServiceResult success(Object msg) {
        ServiceResult serviceResult = new ServiceResult();
        serviceResult.setCode(SUCCESS);
        serviceResult.setMsg(msg);
        return serviceResult;
    }
}
```

I am just not sure what else I can do here, Class is serializable and do have all member fields which are serializable as well.

Please do let me know if this has been tackled before.

Comment: `Object` does not implement `Serializable`.

Comment: how to make object implement Serializable

Comment: You can't. One way would be to simply replace `Object` with `Serializable`, but the first question should be what kind of messages you are expecting. Is that really an arbitrary object?

Comment: thanks~the msg should be a string rather than an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 1):

This SonarQube rule requires that all fields of a serializable class must also be serializable (or marked as [`transient`](https://www.javatpoint.com/transient-keyword), so that they are ignored during a serialization).

The `Object` class does not implement `Serializable`, so the following line violates that rule:

```
private Object msg;
```

To resolve this issue, either exclude `msg` from serialization by making it `transient` or change the type from `Object` to `String` or any other class that implements `Serializable`.